# List implementation in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm a C beginner and I tried an implementation of lists in C, but when I compile the code I receive the error "request for member 'words' in something that not in a structure or union". My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct data {
    char* word;
    struct data* next;
} DataT;

typedef struct node {
    int wordLength;
    struct node* prev, *next;
    DataT* words;
} NodeT;

typedef struct list {
    int length;
    NodeT* first , *last;
} ListT;


void insertWord(NodeT* Node, char* word) {
    if(!Node) || (!word) return;

    if(Node.words.word == NULL)
        Node.words.word = word;

    DataT* current = Node.words.next;

    while(current)
    {
        current = current.next;
    }
    (*current.next) = word;
}
```

Comment: `Node` is pointer, so you need `Node->words`.

Comment: `if(!Node) || (!word) return;` won't compile. Try again.

Comment: I would suggest if you are a beginner, you implement a simply linked list using only the first `DataT` struct definition. When that is working you can go on to the more complex case you are trying. This will enable you to at least get the correct syntax without struggling with too many concepts. For example, another syntax error (see joop) is using the `.` syntax to access a field from a `struct` pointer, where you should be using `->` see the helpful answer from Vlad.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JAfq6ep1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in the function implementation

For example this if statement is syntactically wrong

```
if(!Node) || (!word) return;
```

I think you mean

```
if( !Node || !word ) return;
```

This statement

```
if(Node.words.word == NULL)
    Node.words.word = word;
```

is also wrong. Should be

```
if(Node->words->word == NULL)
    Node->words->word = word;
```

Again invalid code

```
DataT* current = Node.words.next;
```

there should be

```
DataT* current = Node->words->next;
```

and this statement is wrong

```
    current = current.next;
```

it should look like

```
    current = current->next;
```

and this statement wrong

```
(*current.next) = word;
```

Moreover after the loop current will be equal to NULL. So you may not access data member next even if you will write correctly `current->next` instead of `current.next`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error comes with the if condition

```
if(!Node) || (!word) return;
```

You should write it as

```
if( !Node || !word ) return;
```

And instead of using dot operator you should use "->"

As you mentioned you are a beginner I would like to show you a simple linked list implementation.I am also a beginner and I implemented linked list this way which is quit simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
int data;
struct node *next;
};

struct node *tail; //Which points to the last node
struct node *current;//used for traversing the list
struct node *new_node; //Newly allocated block of memory(node)
struct node *head; //Head of list


void create(int number){
new_node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
new_node->next=NULL;
new_node->data=number;
if (head==NULL){

    head=new_node;
    tail=new_node;
}
else
    tail->next=new_node;
    tail=new_node;
    current=head;
}


int display(struct node *current){
current=head;
  printf("\n");
  while(current!=NULL){
  printf("%d-->",current->data);
  current=current->next;
  }printf("NULL\n");
  return 0;
  }



 int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
 int number,choice;
 while(1){
    printf("\n1.Creae Node\n");
    printf("\n2.Display\n");
    printf("\n3.Exit\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch (choice){

        case 1: printf("Enter number-->\t");
            scanf("%d",&number);
            create(number);
            break;
        case 2: display(current);
            break;
        case 3: exit(-1);
    }   
    }       
return  0;
    }
```

I would suggest you to go through  pointers dynamic,memory allocation and structures before starting implementing data structures.